# Further (speed) improvements to SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

i have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT Frage_ID 
FROM Session_Fragen 
WHERE 
    (
        Userantwort1 = 0 
        AND Userantwort2 = 0 
        AND Userantwort3 = 0 
        AND Userantwort4 = 0 
        AND Userantwort5 = 0
    ) AND Session_ID = 17898 
ORDER BY Sessionfrage_ID ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Initially this query run very slow.
So i added index to improve the speed.
Bevor using indexes i scanned all approx. 500.000 rows ...
After using indexes i reduced the rows to approx. 550 (depends on results)
But the query still takes > 2 sec. to run.

Does anybody see further improvements?

---

Explain of the Statement:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  Session_Fragen  index   Session_Fragen_big_index_2,Session_Fragen_big_inde...   PRIMARY     8   NULL    535     Using where
```

---

SHOW INDEXES:

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name     Collation   Cardinality     Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment
Session_Fragen  0   PRIMARY     1   Sessionfrage_ID     A   573447  NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Frage_ID    1   Frage_ID    A   3018    NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index_2  1   Userantwort1    A   2   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index_2  2   Userantwort2    A   3   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index_2  3   Userantwort3    A   5   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index_2  4   Userantwort4    A   7   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index_2  5   Userantwort5    A   9   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index    1   Session_ID  A   14703   NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index    2   Frage_ID    A   573447  NULL    NULL        BTREE   
Session_Fragen  1   Session_Fragen_big_index    3   Sessionfrage_ID     A   573447  NULL    NULL        BTREE
```

---

TABLE STRUCTURE:

```
Table   Create Table
Session_Fragen  CREATE TABLE `Session_Fragen` ( 
    `Sessionfrage_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `User_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,  
    `SF_Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
    `Session_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,  
    `Frage_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,  
    `Userantwort1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `Userantwort2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `Userantwort3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `Userantwort4` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `Userantwort5` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    PRIMARY KEY (`Sessionfrage_ID`),  
    KEY `Frage_ID` (`Frage_ID`),  
    KEY `Session_Fragen_big_index_2` (`Userantwort1`,`Userantwort2`,`Userantwort3`,`Userantwort4`,`Userantwort5`),  
    KEY `Session_Fragen_big_index` (`Session_ID`,`Frage_ID`,`Sessionfrage_ID`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=767877 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Consider creating separate indexes for each `UserantwortX` field

Comment: Hmm. I realized, that the improvements above did not lead to success. The queries still take 2 seconds and more. does anybode has another idea for improvements?

Comment: given that you are using MyISAM tables, maybe you should increase the size of the key buffer. I had some issues some time ago with MyISAM tables and that helped me. Check [my question and its answers on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663515/mysql-what-is-the-key-buffer)

Comment: I would suggest modifying index `Session_Fragen_big_index_2` to include Session_ID, e.g. like so: KEY `Session_Fragen_big_index_2` (`Session_ID`, `Userantwort1`,`Userantwort2`,`Userantwort3`,`Userantwort4`,`Userantwort5`). This should bring down rows which are examined further. Depending on the structure of the data in might be beneficial to even include `Sessionfrage_ID` as a last item in this big index to be able to add a subquery to the SELECT which allows to bring down examined rows to 1 (as right now you are using a LIMIT 1 which is not optimal as it requires sorting)!