# PHP: Filtering and export large amount of data from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo

I have a very large database table (more than 700k records) that I need to export to a .csv file. Before exporting it, I need to check some options (provided by the user via GUI) and filter the records. Unfortunately this filtering action cannot be achieved via SQL code (for example, a column contains serialized data, so I need to unserialize and then check if the record "passes" the filtering rules.

Doing all records at once leads to memory limit issues, so I decided to break the process in chunks of 50k records. So instead of loading 700k records at once, I'm loading 50k records, apply filters, save to the .csv file, then load other 50k records and go on (until it reaches the 700k records). In this way I'm avoiding the memory issue, but it takes around 3 minutes (This time will increase if the number of records increase).

Is there any other way of doing this process (better in terms of time) without changing the database structure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could mess around with [key_buffers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663515/mysql-what-is-the-key-buffer), switch from InnoDB to MyISAM while reading and then switch back and I'm sure there are other ways, aspecially doddling with the mysql config.

Comment: 700K rows is medium sized. *Very large* in a modern system is more than 100M rows.

Comment: Sorry @OllieJones, I didn't know about that

Comment: I would say this is a standard solution to this problem. Why do you think doing it in one go would be quicker? Is the batch-select particularly slow? What are you actually trying to optimise?

Comment: So is it normal if it takes around 3 minutes @scipilot? I never exported a database this big, so I'm not sure about what is an acceptable time

Comment: It all depends on the server(s) horsepower and where the bottlenecks are. It  could be many things either in the queries or in the post-processing, resulting from CPU/Network/Disk IO/Memory limits on either machines. You'd need to profile each operation stage and focus on the slowest part. Simple timestamped debug-logging either side of the query calls and the key post-processing steps would illuminate this. I'd start with four timestamps: begin, after select, after processing, after save.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing one can do is to get PHP out of the mix as much as possible. Always the case for loading CSV, or exporting it.

In the below, I have a 26 Million row student table. I will export 200K rows of it. Granted, the column count is small in the student table. Mostly for testing other things I do with campus info for students. But you will get the idea I hope. The issue will be how long it takes for your:

> ... and then check if the record "passes" the filtering rules.

which naturally could occur via the db engine in theory without PHP. Without PHP should be the mantra. But that is yet to be determined. The point is, get PHP processing out of the equation. PHP is many things. An adequate partner in DB processing it is not.

```
select count(*) from students;
-- 26.2 million

select * from students limit 1;
+----+-------+-------+
| id | thing | camId |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |     1 |    14 |
+----+-------+-------+

drop table if exists xOnesToExport;
create table xOnesToExport
(   id int not null
);
insert xOnesToExport (id) select id from students where id>1000000 limit 200000;
-- 200K rows, 5.1 seconds

alter table xOnesToExport ADD PRIMARY KEY(id); 
-- 4.2 seconds

SELECT s.id,s.thing,s.camId INTO OUTFILE 'outStudents_20160720_0100.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  FROM students s
  join xOnesToExport x
  on x.id=s.id;
-- 1.1 seconds
```

The above 1AM timestamped file with 200K rows was exported as a CSV via the join. It took 1 second.

[`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) and [`SELECT INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) are companion functions that, for one one thing, cannot be beat for speed short of raw table moves. Secondly, people rarely seem to use the latter. They are flexible too if one looks into all they can do with use cases and tricks.

For Linux, use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` ... I am on a Windows machine at the moment with the code blocks above. The only differences tend to be with paths to the file, and the line terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you tell it to do otherwise, php slurps your entire result set at once into RAM. It's called a *buffered query.* It doesn't work when your result set contains more than a few hundred rows, as you have discovered.

php's designers made it use buffered queries to make life simpler for web site developers who need to read a few rows of data and display them.

You need an [*unbuffered query*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php) to do what you're doing. Your php program will read and process one row at a time. But be careful to make your program read all the rows of that unbuffered result set; you can really foul things up if you leave a partial result set dangling in limbo between MySQL and your php program.

You didn't say whether you're using `mysqli` or `PDO`. Both of them offer mode settings to make your queries unbuffered. If you're using the old-skool `mysql_` interface, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Thanks @Ollie Jones. I'm using PDO. Your suggestion will decrease the memory usage, but is not going to increase the load in the server?

Comment: Not sure what server you mean. It won't hurt the MySQL server; in fact it will help because you're only running one query, rather than a bunch of them. You won't have to use `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` clauses to generate your shards.     Your web server running your php program will have about the same level of work to do either way. Three minutes isn't unreasonable, especially if this stuff is in a shared server at a commercial hosting service.

Comment: If I use unbuffered queries, is the table be locked until the end of the process or will it be available to be read/written by another processes?